# Calculating $E[X^2|X+Y]$ for $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I know that $E[X|X+Y]=\frac{1}{2}(X+Y)$ for $X,Y$ i.i.d., so I was thinking maybe $E[X^2|X+Y]=\frac{1}{4}(X+Y)^2$, since if we can "approximate" $X$ with respect to $X+Y$ by $\frac{1}{2}(X+Y)$, then $X^2$ ought to be approximable by the square of that, but I'm having trouble confirming or disproving this. The standard method I know for conditional expectations is finding the density $f(x,y)$ of the joint distribution $(X^2,X+Y)$ and calculating $g(y)=\frac{\int xf(x,y)dx}{\int f(x,y)dx}$, but that's not working either (the squared factor is giving me trouble).

Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: $E[X^2|X+Y]=\frac{1}{4}(X+Y)^2$ is not correct. Expectation if LHS is $EX^{2}$ and that of RHS is $\frac 1  2 EX^{2}$ if #EX=0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm you're right, I didn't consider that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually $E(X^{2}|X+Y)=\frac 1  4(X+Y)^{2}+\frac 1 2$ if $X,Y$ is i.i.d. $N(0,1)$.  To see this note that $E(X^{2}|X+Y)=E(Y^{2}|X+Y)$ since the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ does not change when you interchange $X$ and $Y$. Also, $E((X-Y)^{2}|X+Y)=E(X-Y)^{2}=2$ because $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent. [This is a special property of normal distribution]. Hence, $E[2(X^{2}+Y^{2})|X+Y]=E[(X+Y)^{2}+(X-Y)^{2}|X+Y)=(X+Y)^{2}+2$ which gives $4E[X^{2}|X+Y]=(X+Y)^{2}+2$. Finally, $E[X^{2}|X+Y]=\frac 1  4(X+Y)^{2}+\frac 1 2$.

Comment: How come $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent? I was actually trying to do what you did, but I did not know this one fact.

Comment: @V.Ch. $\mathrm{cov}(X+Y,X-Y)=0$

Comment: For jointly normal r.v 's independence is equivalent to zero covariance.

Answer (score 3):

As a consequence of the formula
$$\operatorname{Var}(X \: | \: X+Y) = \operatorname{E}[X^2 \: | \: X+Y] - \operatorname{E}[X \: | \: X+Y]^2,$$
we get that
$$\operatorname{E}[X^2 \: | \: X+Y] = \operatorname{Var}(X \: | \: X+Y) + \operatorname{E}[X \: | \: X+Y]^2.$$
Now, since $X \: | \: X+Y \sim N(\frac{X+Y}{2} , \frac{1}{2})$ we get that
$$\operatorname{E}[X^2 \: | \: X+Y] = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{(X+Y)^2}{4}.$$

Comment: Thanks, that was very slick!